In Odoo 17, how can I limit the radio button choices based on the choices on the other fields
I need to make the radio button option to only "container" when the values of the other fields are as follows: direction='export', transport='ocean' and ocean_shipment_type='fcl'.
Here are the snippets of models involved:
class FreightShipment(models.Model):
    _name = 'freight.shipment'

    direction = fields.Selection(([('import', 'Import'), ('export', 'Export')]), string='Direction')
    transport = fields.Selection(([('air', 'Air'), ('ocean', 'Ocean'), ('land', 'Land')]),
                                 string='Transport Via')
    ocean_shipment_type = fields.Selection(([('fcl', 'Full Container(FCL)'),
                                             ('lcl', 'Less Container(LCL)')]),
                                           string='Ocean Shipment Type')
    freight_packages = fields.One2many('shipment.package.line', 'shipment_id')

    ...

class ShipmentPackageLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'shipment.package.line'
    _rec_name = 'package'

     package_type = fields.Selection([('item', 'Loose Cargo'), ('container', 'Containerized')],
                                    string="Package Type", default='item')
     ...

Here is the XML view snippet
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="freight_shipment_form_view">
   <field name="name">freight.shipment.form.view</field>
   <field name="model">freight.shipment</field>
   ...
   <sheet>
      ...
      <div class="oe_title mb24">
         <h1>
            <field class="text-break" name="name" default_focus="1" readonly="1"/>
         </h1>
         <h3>
            <field name="direction" widget="radio" required="1" options="{'horizontal': true}"/>
         </h3>
      </div>
      ...
      <group string="Transport Details">
         <field name="is_transport_read_only" invisible="1"/>
         <group>
            <field name="transport" widget="radio" options="{'horizontal': true}" required="1" readonly="is_transport_read_only"/>
         </group>
         <group>
            <field name="ocean_shipment_type" invisible="transport != 'ocean'" required="transport == 'ocean'"/>
            <field name="inland_shipment_type" invisible="transport != 'land'" required="transport == 'land'"/>
         </group>
      </group>
      ...
      <notebook>
         ...
        <page string="Package Details" invisible="direction != 'export'">
           <field name="freight_packages" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list">
              <tree string="Package">
                 <field name="name" required="1"/>
                 ...
              </tree>
              <form string="Package">
                 <group>
                    <label for="package_type"/>
                    <div>
                       <field name="package_type" widget="radio" options="{'horizontal':True}"/>
                    </div>
                 </group>
                 <group invisible="package_type != 'container'">
                    <group string="Containerized">
                       <field name="name" required="1"/>
                    </group>
                    ...
                 <group invisible="package_type != 'item'">
                    <group string="Loose Cargo">
                       <field name="name" required="1"/>
                    </group>
                 ...

I asked Microsoft Co-Pilot and this was its answer but nothing happens. I placed it in the FreightShipment class
@api.onchange('direction', 'transport', 'ocean_shipment_type')
def _onchange_shipment_conditions(self):
   for package in self.freight_packages:
      if self.direction == 'export' and self.transport == 'ocean' and self.ocean_shipment_type == 'fcl':
         package.package_type = 'container'
         package.fields_get()['package_type']['selection'] = [('container', 'Containerized')]
      else:
         package.fields_get()['package_type']['selection'] = [('item', 'Loose Cargo'), ('container', 'Containerized')]

What should I do?

I mean the onchanged decorator, just gonna trigger when ever the form is saved (which is not the case here). You can try to changed the selection fields into Many2one fields and limit the answer using domain. For example take a look as this use case where a limit district base on city, ward base on district.
The model:
class district(models.Model):
    _name = "res.country.state.district"
    _description = "Store all the district in the world"


    name = fields.Char()
    state_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state')
    district_code = fields.Char()


class ward(models.Model):
    _name = "res.country.state.district.ward"
    _description = "Store all the world in the world"

    name = fields.Char()
    district_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state.district')

The fields' domain declare to limit it:
district_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state.district',
                               string='District',
                               domain="[('state_id', '=?', state_id)]",
                               help='Choose the district of the contact')
   ward = fields.Many2one('res.country.state.district.ward',
                           string='Ward',
                           domain="[('district_id', '=?', district_id)]",
                           help='Choose the ward of the contact')

Note that: The 2 fields specify in the domain is in the 2 model participating in the relationship.
And also note that: You may need to look furthur into odoo document for specifying the right domain based on your use case

I learned that fields.Selection cannot be changed/dynamic. It is only possible if I changed it to Many2one, but I need to create a model/object for that and create a new table in the database and fill its values. I just did a workaround using @api.depends that make a value default and the field read-only
